# How can I create multiple operations for the same domain on GPT Builder?

Tags: yaml, openai-api, chat-gpt-4

I am looking to feed back different responses from my server based on the query which a person enters on my custom [franchising ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/g/g-JHfYFvZ8P-franchisegpt).

I have created an operation action which listens for the term "low cost franchises", and on my server will process a response based on this query.

```
paths:
  /gpt.php:
    get:
      operationId: low cost franchises
      summary: Find me the best low cost franchises UK
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: query
          required: true
          description: Query
          schema:
            type: string
```

I would like to process more queries, however adding more actions results in an error saying I cannot add multiple actions for the same domain.

Unfamiliar with Yaml (I did put my code in as JSON but it converted it to Yaml), I would like feedback please on which blocks to add to the code I have so far, so that I can append other variations of the query. I'm guessing I need to add another `operationId` block underneath the existing one? Despite my testing I keep hitting rate limiting to come back in several hours.

Can't say i've spent particularly long looking at it, I can't see anyone using it given the $20 a month paywall imposed by OpenAi. I'd do more trial and error if it wasn't for the use rate limiting of the builder...